# Placeholder text in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

When placeholder text is needed, what text should be used?

In this example for background color, `Look out!` is used as placeholder text.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/296/backgrounds/1055/background-color#t=201607202320450759969

**HTML**

```
<div class="warning">Look out!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.warning {
    background-color: red;
}
```

`Look out!` feels kind of out of place. Placeholder text should be more generic and in some way uniform across examples, at least within a topic. I'd like to edit this example. How should I proceed?

Comment: "Here be dragons!" perhaps? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Haha! That's my edit. :) I chose this text in order to make the example more semantically correct. I feel it's better to use examples demonstrating semantics than things like "#myDiv" and "This is red."

Answer (score 2):

For a warning, "look out" makes sense to me. It's a pretty common phrase you'd hear if, say, there was a hazard in front of you and you weren't paying attention while walking. In other words, a warning. :)

I wouldn't edit the example in this case. I think the choice of text there illustrates the point and a more generic phrasing (e.g. "This is a warning") would still be fine, but wouldn't necessarily have the same ... whimsy. It's okay to be a little creative in examples.

When in doubt, there's always [lorem ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/), but in most cases I think the best approach is to use whatever text makes sense in the context of the example.

Comment: Thanks for the defense, Adam. :) Though I wasn't expecting to ever find my contributions characterized as whimsical! lol

Comment: @NathanArthur Ahh, semantical correctness. That's the phrase I was looking for. ;)

Comment: The example is for background color, not for warnings in particular. It feels a little strange for each example to be a specific use case instead of a generic placeholder that demonstrates just the idea at hand.

Comment: @Goose I actually agree, and I haven't made changes like that very often. I think this is a good discussion to have. The answer isn't obvious to me, either.